# Is it better for speed and reliability to use one domain, or multiple (sub)domains?

Tags: web-hosting, web-development, subdomain, multi-subdomains, development

I have a plan to start a website with different topics and tools. And my doubt here is... is it okay to present all these topics on a single domain (example.com), or is it better to make some subdomain for each category?

In this case, I want to consider the reliability and loading speed.

Answer (score 1):

From a speed point of view  definitely 1 domain. This results in fewer DNS lookups and the ability to reuse connections which speed things up.

Reliability is a complex issue. Its likely better solved with good DNS infrastructure and hosting - possibly leveraging a reverse proxy / caching system like Cloudflare to boost speed and resiliency - and/or, depending in the content, maybe having multiple servers  serving the content.

The only thing I see multiple domains providing is resiliency against the domain name being taken away - if you are not doing stuff governments don't approve of, long term registrations through reputable registrars (and ysing 2fa) can largely offset this risk.

Comment: I don't think they were considering multiple domains,  it looks like the question was between a single host name, or multiple sub-domains of a single domain.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller multiple domains or multiple subdomains of a single domain is mostly the same thing DNS-wise (but has differences in web security sense, the "eTLD+1" thing for cookies, etc.). But I disagree with @.davidgo, regarding speed, if the DNS is properly set up (without too low TTLs) and the site successful, then there won't be any speed differences as the results of resolution will stay in caches.

Comment: Still, I haven't got the exact answer to the question. The question is to do different things on a website like web applications, blogs, etc. it is good to create a single domain like example.com or create multiple domains like blog.example.com, app.example.com, student.example.com, etc. is good.

Comment: From a speed pov there is nothing in it.  DNS lookups are a trivial part of the equation and thesecare not topics as much as applications.  From the POV if SEO  (which may not be relevant and was not asked), subdomains are mych harder to rank.  On the flip side, gaving multiple subdomains will allow you to spread your load more easily - so where you don't need SEI it may be better to use a subdomain, while keeping content that dies require SEO on the main domain.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification!